# weird issue in an SDL-based Hanoi Tower Game

Tags: c++, class, infinite-loop

I want to create a SDL-based Hanoi Tower Game, but before I proceed to writing "engine", I wanted to test my Hanoi in a console. Surprisingly, it turned out to be quite buggy.

```
CTower tower[3];

tower[0] = CTower(3);
tower[1] = CTower(3);
tower[2] = CTower(3);

init(&tower[0]);  //prepare first tower
tower[0].Print();
```

This piece of code should create 3 arrays (of size 3) and fill 'em with 0 (zeros). Then, in init(), I prepare the first tower (fill it with vaild discs). However simple may it seem, my application halts on printing and doesn't fill the remaining arrays (with 0). What's strange, function init() works just fine.

I would appreciate any help.

Here's some code to check:

```
class CTower {
    uint16 *floors, floorsNum;

    void Init();

  public:
    (...) //definitions, probably of zero importance
};

void CTower::Init() {
  //private member, filling with zeros
  for (uint16 i = 0; i < floorsNum; i++)
    floors[i] = 0;
}
CTower::CTower() {
  //default initialiazer
  floors = NULL;
  floorsNum = 0;
}
CTower::CTower(uint16 nfloors) {
  floors = new uint16[nfloors];
  floorsNum = nfloors;
  this->Init();
}
CTower::~CTower() {
  delete[] floors;
  floorsNum = 0;
}
void CTower::Print() {
  if (floorsNum == 0) printf("EMPTY TOWER!");
  else
    for (uint16 i = 0; i < floorsNum; i++)
      printf("%d\n", floors[i]);
}
void init(CTower *tower) {
  //a friend method of CTower
  for (uint16 i = 0; i < tower->floorsNum; i++)
    tower->floors[i] = i+1;
}
```

My application source: https://rapidshare.com/files/2229751163/hanoi-tower.7z

Comment: I think your `};` of the class should be at the end, i.e. after of the methods.

Comment: You could also put a break point on the print method and find out what value `floorNum` has.

Comment: Would you mind showing the `init` function as well? Also, have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Show more code. Do you have destructor or assignment operator defined for your CTower class?

Comment: The problem is probably in init(&tower[0]);, show us that function also.

Comment: This is not entirely the code you use - the function here is called `Init` with capital letter instead of lowercase. Also I can see that the `floorsNum` is always 0. Isn't it expected to be increased in the `Init` function?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev How can it be 0 when I call a proper initialiazer: CTower(uint16 nfloor). CTower::Init() fills with 0, init(CTower *tower) fills with 1, 2, 3, ..., n.

Comment: @Henrik
yeah, but I don't think it causes the problem. nevertheless i'm going to post it ;)

Comment: @Robin92 - You need to give us the code of `init` for us to help you (as @Kristofer asked for 40 minutes ago).

Comment: I cannot see any problem with the code supplied. The output would be 1 2 3 (on separate lines). What do you mean halting? What output do you get?

Comment: @EdHeal
I know and that's the problem.

I've uploaded the files. Feel free to test them.

Comment: @Robin92 what is the problem with getting "1 2 3" on separate lines ?

Comment: @Coren what? i don't understand

Comment: Just a small comment - your array definition (tower[3]) already calls the default ctor for each item in the array. You then create another instance for each tower and override your original towers. You might want to change that.

Comment: @Robin92 I have finally seen your problem. It's halting at the second Print() call, and it's totally normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with your *initialisation* and allocation of your class. It seems you have forgotten that [Resource Acquisition is Initialisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). 
You are facing a free corruption : you call *delete[]* on a not allocated attribute.

You have this constructor :

```
CTower::CTower() {
//default initialiazer
floors = NULL;
floorsNum = 0;
}
```

Which does **NOT** allocates memory but which is destroyed with :

```
CTower::~CTower() {
  delete[] floors;
  floorsNum = 0;
}
```

A simple way to fix your program is to allocate directly with the working constructor :

```
int main(void) {
  CTower tower[3] = { CTower(3), CTower(3), CTower(3) };

  init(&tower[0]);
  tower[0].Print();
  printf("\n");
  tower[1].Print();

  return 0;
}
```

But it would be *far* better to also fix your **Class**, either in Destructor or in Constructor part.

Comment: As I've written, `init(CTower *tower)` is a friend of `CTower` thus it has access to all of its very private members.

Comment: with `friend void init(CTower*);` in CTower **class**, it's fully working for me.

Comment: God damn it, so what's going on? Is is that cursed CodeBlocks?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have been specifically asked not to use a std::vector then I would consider changing your code to use one as it makes life a lot simpler.

With regards to your specific code example. You are going to have problems due to the lack of a copy constructor and assignment operator as the defaults generated by the compiler are not going to be suitable for your class.

I would also consider getting rid of the friend function void init(CTower *tower) as this really isn't good practice.

I would provide a code example but this question is tagged as "Homework" so I will let you do the research yourself.